# "Connection refused" when connecting to FTP port 990 in Java

Tags: java, ftp, ftps, apache-commons-net

I made an array of FTPS clients and tried to connect it to the ip & port of my interest. Here is the code.

```
public class ftptest 
{   
    public static void delete_files(String path, int n) throws IOException
    {
        String realpath;
        for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++)
        {
            realpath = path+i;
            File file = new File(realpath);
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(file);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        int number = 1;
        String ip = "some_ip";
        int port = 990;

        FTPSClient[] client = new FTPSClient[number];

        System.out.println(ip);
        System.out.println("port = "+ port);


        for(int i = 0; i < number; i++)
        {
            String path = "D:\\ftptest\\client"+i;          
            File file = new File(path);
            file.mkdir();       


            client[i] = new FTPSClient(true);   
            client[i].setRemoteVerificationEnabled(false);
            client[i].setTrustManager
            (TrustManagerUtils.getAcceptAllTrustManager());         

            client[i].enterLocalPassiveMode();


            client[i].setControlEncoding("UTF-8");
            client[i].connect(ip,port);

            System.out.println("Connected to " + ip + ".");
        }   
    }
}
```

but somehow it fails in the `client[i].connect(ip, port)` part with the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: >connect
>     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
>     at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
>     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:182)
>     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:203)
>     at org.apache.commons.net.SocketClient.connect(SocketClient.java:296)
>     at com.samsung.ftptest.ftptest.main(ftptest.java:66)

When it is FTP, not FTPS, it is working fine. Does anybody have any idea why it is not working?

Thank you.

Comment: maybe ftp server is not set up for ftps?

Comment: @Scary Wombat thanks for the comment. Then you would assume that there is nothing wrong with the code itself? BTW, I changed client[i] = new FTSClient("true") to client[i] = new FTSClient(true), deleting the quotation marks.

Comment: Sorry, I am not making that assumption for you

Comment: *"but somehow it fails"* Like how does it fail? Show stacktrace.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
is what I'm getting..

Comment: What port are you connecting to? Can you connect to the same port from the same machine using any standalone FTP(S) client?

Comment: @Martin, I'm connecting to port 990 as of now. When I'm using FTP, I'm using port 21 and it is working fine. I chopped some codes down below, but originally this was to download some photos from the given server. When using FTP, it is downloading the photos and is working fine. Problem is when using FTPS. I do not know what I am missing to get the ConnectionException..

Comment: Again, can you connect to the same port from the same machine using any standalone FTP(S) client? - Why do you even you the implicit mode?

Comment: Why did you use 990? Presumably you've proved this server works with some other client -- what port does this use? Why are you using deprectated implicit FTPS anyway?  (`new FTPSClient(true)`)

Comment: Try adding the boolean parameter true to the c'tor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The system on which you're running this, can't connect to port 990 on the server machine. There are a number of reasons this could be the case, including:

- The server is not listening on port 990
- A firewall is blocking port 990

The first thing you should do is find a client that's successfully connecting to this server using FTPS, and check its configuration:

- What port is it configured to use?
- Is it using:

  - explicit FTPS (this is the preferred, standards-compliant way to do FTPS. It connects in plain FTP on port 21, then negotiates up to a secured protocol.
  - implicit FTPS (this approach has never been a standard, but does occur in the wild. Like HTTPS, a different port (often 990) is used, and an SSL handshakes happens immediately after connection)

Once you know these things, you can put the right port and the right mode into your code.

If you're certain of the port, and that it works from other machines, then a firewall is the likely culprit. Demonstrate that you can't connect, using telnet:

```
 unixprompt$ telnet serverhostname 990
```

If it hangs, or says "Connection refused", you know that this machine can't reach it. If you get "Connected to ..." you know that at least you have TCP connectivity (then `ctrl-] quit` to get out).

If you find that it's a firewall, be prepared for a battle. You're struggling with the control connection -- data connections are a whole new fight. Opening firewalls for passive mode explicit FTPS is fairly straightforward, and documented in this IETF draft: https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-fordh-ftp-ssl-firewall-00   -- but firewall admins are notoriously reluctant to do it.

Comment: Thanks alot for the kind and specific answer. Turns out, the server of interest was not supporting port 990. Changing to port 21 shifted the problem to the another one -  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException:. It is problem after problem, but your solution was right! Thanks alot and have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

The server probably does not support the (deprecated) implicit FTPS mode.

You better use the explicit mode anyway:

```
client[i] = new FTPSClient();   
// ...
client[i].connect(ip, 21);
```

*(assuming the server does support FTP over TLS/SSL at all)*

Comment: We can't guess whether the server is standards compliant explicit mode, or deprecated implicit mode. OP should test with a known-to-work client.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. In my case, neither worked out :(

Comment: From your comment to the other question, it seems that my solution did work. That it brought another problem is a different topic.